# what is the meaning of "pragma style" in webpack?

Tags: webpack

in the [devtool configuration docs](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) they say:

> Prefixing @, # or #@ will enforce a pragma style. (Defaults to #,
>   recommended)

what it the meaning of that?

Comment: This refers to a C preprocessor. It just provides more clues to the compiler about what it should do.

Comment: Hi erip, could you point me to some information about it?
found nothing on google..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Different browsers require different formats for specifying sourcemaps. If your browser isn't showing sourcemaps for webpack'd files, then you can change that option to make it compatible with your browser.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, sirlancelot.
I googled "sourcemaps pragma style" and found nothing about it.
could you point me to some information about it?

Comment: The only info I could really find about it is here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/#toc-howwork

Answer (score 22):

To be a bit more explicit about this, the "pragma" being referred to is a sequence of characters that signify metadata to the browser.  In this case, the metadata tells the browser where to fetch the source map file, should it decide to load it (e.g., when the user opens the browser dev tools).

As indicated in the link from sirlancelot, the standard format for the pragma is to use a comment of the following form, starting with `//#`:

`//# sourceMappingURL=/path/to/file.js.map`

In recent versions of Webpack, if you do not specify a pragma character in your `devtool` setting, then it defaults to using the `#` character after the comment characters, as shown above.

In older versions of Webpack though, the pragma character used to default to `@`, which would result in a comment of the form:

`//@ sourceMappingURL=/path/to/file.js.map`

Using the `//@` form in a recent browser will result in a deprecation warning in the browser console now (in Chrome at least).

If you need to support an older browser, you can override the default pragma by prefixing your `devtool` setting with the desired character, for example:

`devtool: "@source-map"`

or set it explicitly to `#` with:

`devtool: "#source-map"`

but it's cleanest IMO to just leave out the prefix character and let Webpack add the default by specifying it as:

`devtool: "source-map"`

Comment: Thank you, this is a much more helpful answer.