# What does the pound sign (#) means in Webpack's devtool option?

Tags: webpack

Some Webpack configuration files prefix the `devtool` option with a pound sign (#). For example, the webpack templates used by `vue-cli` do that. What is the meaning of that? What is the difference between setting `eval-source-map` and `#eval-sourcemap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html).

> Prefixing @, # or #@ will enforce a pragma style. (Defaults to @ in
>   webpack@1 and # in webpack@2; using # is recommended)

"Pragma style" in WebPack is simply the format for specyfing sourcemaps, if sourcemaps for WebPacked files don't work in your browser then you can change that prefix and it should help.

It's very well explained in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756853/what-is-the-meaning-of-pragma-style-in-webpack).

Hope it helps!

Comment: link is dead, and the new docs dont contain this info. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ very strange